# Multiple formsets only saves the number of formsets in 'extra' attribute: Why?

Tags: django

**Short version**: Creating dynamically multiple formsets only saves as much formsets specified in *extra* attribute instead of as many as I've.

**Long version**: I'm doing my first project with Django and I've to create a CreateView with a Parent and a Child forms. I need to create as many nested Child forms the user wants, so I've created a small code in Javascript that adds/removes the child forms. This is working fine.

The problem is: I can only save as many forms as I've specified in the *extra* attribute. If I say '3', it creates 3 Child forms and I can save 3 of them, even if I create/remove Child forms. If I say '1', I can create 10, but only will save 1. Seems like I'm missing something in the template, but I don't know what. Here's the relevant code:

**forms.py**

```
class ParentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Parent
        exclude = ()

class ChildForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Child
        fields = ....

ChildFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Parent, Child, form=ChildForm, can_delete=True, extra=1)
```

**views.py**

```
class ParentCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Entrada
    fields = ...

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(ParentCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            data['child_form'] = ChildFormSet(self.request.POST)
            data['materials'] = Material.objects.all()
        else:
            data['child_form'] = ChildFormSet()
            data['materials'] = Material.objects.all()
        return data

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        child_form = context['child_form']
        with transaction.atomic():
            self.object = form.save()
            if child_form.is_valid():
                child_form.instance = self.object
                child_form.field1 = self.object.id 
                child_form.save()
        return super(ParentCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

**template.html**

```
<form class="own-form" action="" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for hidden_field in form.hidden_fields %}
  {{ hidden_field }}
{% endfor %}
<h2 class="text-center text-header"> New Entry</h2>

<div class="form-group">
{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-4 text-center">{{ field.label_tag }}</div>
    <div class="col-8">{{ field }}</div>
    {% if field.help_text %}
      <small class="form-text text-muted">{{ field.help_text }}</small>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
<hr>

<div class="form-group form-material-box row form-0">
  <div class="col-3 text-center">
    <label>Total weight: </label>
    <input type="number" id="kg_0">
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 text-center">
    <label>Boxes to create: </label>
    <input type="number" id="num_boxes_0">
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 text-center">
    <label>Material: </label>
    <br>
    <select name="item_id" id="material_0">
      {% for material in materials %}
        <option value="{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ material }}</option>
      {% endfor %}
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 text-center">
    <button type="button" id="create_boxes_0" class="btn btn-danger">Create</button>
  </div>

  <!-- Nested forms with desired number of boxes -->
  <div id="nested_forms_0">
    <div class="row" id="box_0">
      {% for bala in bala_form %}
      <div class="col-3 text-center">
        <h5>Bala #1: </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-2 text-center">
        {{ bala.kg }}
      </div>
      <div class="col-2 text-center" >
        {{ bala.material }}
      </div>
      <div class="col-2 text-center" >
        {{ bala.box_price }}
      </div>
      <div class="col-3 text-center">
        <button type="button" id='remove_box_0' class="btn btn-danger">Remove box</button>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<p>
  {{ child_form.management_form }}
  <input id="create" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg btn-block btn-option btn-form" type="submit" value="Crear" />
</p>
```

*Edit*:

**javascript relevant code**

```
// Adds the difference between desired boxes and current boxes
function add_boxes(form_id, total, num){
    for (let i = total; i != total+num; i++) {
      var element = $('#nested_forms_' + form_id + "> :first-child ").clone().css('display', 'none');
      element.appendTo('#nested_forms_' + form_id).show('250');
    };
  $('#id_child-TOTAL_FORMS').val(num + total);
};

// Removes every unneeded boxes
function remove_boxes(form_id, total){
  $('#nested_forms_' + form_id).children().each(function(){
    if ($(this).index() >= total) {
      $(this).fadeTo(150, 0).slideUp(150, function(){
        $(this).remove();
      });
    }
  });
  $('#id_child-TOTAL_FORMS').val(total);
}
```

What I'm missing?

**Update**
I've printed the information passed to Django from the template. Seems like its just getting the empty form without any value when I'm creating more than *extra* forms. Comparing the diffs when I'm creating 3 forms dynamically  (left) and hardcoding 3 as the *extra* value (right) shows it (bales-materies-primeres is the name of the Child):

https://www.diffchecker.com/XskfB9y3

Comment: Show your javascript code to add/remove forms.

Comment: Done. Also I've checked the HTML with the inspector that updates the TOTAL_FORMS value.

Comment: Seems like I'm not getting the context data of the form. Check the 'update' section at the end of the original post.

Comment: Why do you have two `Child` inside `inlineformset_factory()` ?

Comment: whops, it was a mistake when I was chaning the original Model names. It should be Parent, Child.

Comment: What's `bala_form` in the template? Did you set the `prefix` as said (below) by _Daniel Roseman_  ?

Answer (score 0):

Your Javascript needs to modify the value of the `form-TOTAL_FORMS` field in the management form. See the [formsets documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/formsets/#understanding-the-managementform).

Comment: I've edited the original post adding the relevant section of the JS code, and also I've checked that updates the value of the TOTAL_FORMS value.

Comment: Are you sure the field is called `child-TOTAL_FORMS`? I can't see anything that sets the prefix of the formset to "child".

Comment: Yes, as I've said, I checked the HTML with the Chrome inspector. Seems like I'm not getting properly the values from the form, see the update at the OP for more info.